# Files stored in a single directory folder

Tags: windows, automation, user-folders

I am a bit of a batch file noob, so I'd really appreciate your help. I have a ton of files stored in a single directory which I wish to sort into subfolders based on the first word in their filenames. So, I have files like these:

```
C:\Folder\ABC_001
C:\Folder\BCD_001
C:\Folder\CDF_002
C:\Folder\DFE_003
```

And I wish to move all files to subfolders based on the first word, ending up like this:

```
C:\Folder\001\ABC_001
C:\Folder\001\BCD_001
C:\Folder\002\CDF_002
C:\Folder\003\DFE_003
```

This is my code , but it not working

```
@Echo off
PushD C:\folder
for %%A in ("*_*.*") do for /f "tokens=1* delims=-" %%B in ("%%A") do (
     If not exist "%%B" MD "%%B"
     Move "%%A" "%%B\"
)
PopD
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I wish to sort files into subfolders based on the first word in their filenames

> ```
> for %%A in ("*_*.*") do for /f "tokens=1* delims=-" %%B in ("%%A") do (
> ```

The above is broken as you have `-` as a delimeter when it should be `_`.

> ```
> Move "%%A" "%%B\"
> ```

The above is broken as `%%A` does not match your files. It should be `"%%A_%%B"`

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal
PushD folder
for /f "tokens=1* delims=_" %%A in ('dir /b *_*.*') do (
  If not exist "%%B" MD "%%B"
  Move "%%A_%%B" "%%B\"
  )
PopD
endlocal
```

Example:

```
F:\test>dir /b /s folder
F:\test\folder\ABC_001
F:\test\folder\BCD_001
F:\test\folder\CDF_002
F:\test\folder\DFE_003

F:\test>test
        1 file(s) moved.
        1 file(s) moved.
        1 file(s) moved.
        1 file(s) moved.

F:\test>dir /b /s folder
F:\test\folder\001
F:\test\folder\002
F:\test\folder\003
F:\test\folder\001\ABC_001
F:\test\folder\001\BCD_001
F:\test\folder\002\CDF_002
F:\test\folder\003\DFE_003

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Dir - list files and folders - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)
- [For - Looping commands - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- [For - Loop through command output - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know batch script & it's not required by an employer, you'd be better off learning & using PowerShell. While it may seem "wordier" at first, that's a good thing --- when you look at your code six months later & can't remember what you did. :D

The code would look like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -file -path 'c:\Folder' |
   ForEach-Object{
      $newDir = ($_.BaseName -split '_')[-1]
      $NewDir = Join-Path $_.Directory $newDir
      If (!( Test-Path $NewDir )) {
         New-Item -Itemtype Directory -Path $newDir
      }
      Move-Item $_ $NewDir   
}
```

Comment: Dear Sir, thank for you comment , PowerShell look like more difficult for me D: , but anyway i will try. Thanks